# PHP - Submitting Form

Tags: php, forms, email, smtp

I posted earlier about a problem that I had with sending an email to the designated address.

I found out that I had to setup an email server. I installed WAMP and then I had to setup a SMTP server, which I downloaded from [softstack.com](http://softstack.com).

The previous error is gone, but now I have this error:

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550 Invalid recipient:
>   testing@testing.com in C:\wamp\www\process.php on line 56

Code on line 56:

```
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message)):
        $msg = "Thanks for filling out our form";
    else:
        $msg = "Problem sending the message";
    endif; // mail form data
```

I have seen other threads related to this which suggest to use `phpEmailer`, but I am following a tutorial and for don't have a clue why it isn't working.

Comment: I am guessing the those colons are for demonstration?

Comment: I just followed the tutorial... which colons?

Comment: In the first line `if (mail($to, $subject, $message)):` and also after the `else`

Comment: @Varun it's valid syntax http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php otherwise OP would have gotten a totally different notice/warning.

Comment: well they were not put there for demonstration, how come?

Comment: have you tried to use an existing mail address?

Comment: for $to I have the email address I want the mail to be sent to. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with your mail server, not with your PHP installation. Typically your ISP will block you from delivering mail outside of your local domain (in this case, your localhost). WAMP/your SMTP server is not configured nor likely available as a relay server (try using another known and configured SMTP server instead of your local server)

Comment: do you have recommended server?

Comment: If your host does not block it, sendmail-bin (apt-get install sendmail-bin) or EXIM should prove fine for your usage. If outgoing mail is blocked (and on many hosts it will be to prevent spam) you may have to use something like mandrill or mailgun as your SMTP host.

Answer (score 0):

If you check here: http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-error

At **550** error it says:

> It usually defines a non-existent email address on the remote side.

Maybe you should try testing by using one of your own email addresses.

Comment: Do I have to add the email address I want to use for testing to the server?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott Now you use `testing@testing.com` as value for `$to` instead use some valid email that you own like `patrickmcdermott@gmail.com`.

Comment: I have been using my own email. Error still appears